# Hook on creating a menu entry?

Tags: plugins, menus, hooks

I need to run some code after a new item has been inserted into a WordPress [nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

Is there any hook on menu modification or something similar?

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: I removed some irrelevant information from the question. I think now it should be clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [source](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/3.9/wp-includes/nav-menu.php), you find the following actions related to the modifications of the navigational menus:

**Update**:

```
    /**
     * Fires after a navigation menu has been successfully updated.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param int   $menu_id   ID of the updated menu.
     * @param array $menu_data An array of menu data.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', $menu_id, $menu_data );
```

**Create**:

```
    /**
     * Fires after a navigation menu is successfully created.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param int   $term_id   ID of the new menu.
     * @param array $menu_data An array of menu data.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_create_nav_menu', $_menu['term_id'], $menu_data );
```

**Delete**:

```
    /**
     * Fires after a navigation menu has been successfully deleted.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param int $term_id ID of the deleted menu.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_delete_nav_menu', $menu->term_id );
```

I wonder if you mean these hooks?

Comment: Thanks, 'wp_update_nav_menu' is exactly what I was looking for. Next time I'll try to check the source...